# В чем разница volatile и static?

Tags: java

Если я правильно понял, то `static` хранит только последнее записанное в него значение, без разницы сколько потоков обращаются к этой переменной, каждый кто обратиться к ней получит последнее записанное значение.

А `volatile` в свою очередь создается с новым созданным объектом и при обращении к ней из разных потоков он возвращает самое свежее значение своего объекта.

Запутанно объяснил наверное, но вот как то так я понял...

Не знаю насколько принципиальная разница...

Comment: Эти понятия вообще слабо связаны, как "жёлтый" и "квадрат".

Comment: @NickVolynkin хахахаха)) очень весело получилось)

Comment: Табличка "сарказм" ?

Comment: @NickVolynkin не, серьезно) Я просто не слышал таких сравненений , но суть я понял)) Мне казалось, что это очень похожие вещи...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`volatile` означает, что чтение и запись переменной с данным квалификатором является атомарной операцией, при этом любое изменение такой переменной будет видно из других потоков.

`static` никак не связано с многопоточностью, этот модификатор указывает, что переменная не принадлежит объекту, она ассоциирована с классом/интерфейсом. Операции над `static`-переменными не являются потокобезопасными. При этом каждый поток может работать со своей копией статической переменной (если она не объявлена как `volatile`) - соответственно без синхронизации изменения в такую переменную могут быть не видны другим потокам.